# Start learning proof complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lo.logic, proof-complexity

I recently started to read a lot about proof complexity and have been really enjoying what I have been reading. I would really like to learn more about this, but I am having difficulty finding some good beginner material to start with. Would anyone be able to recommend some basics?

Comment: Have you checked the references in the Wikipedia article [proof complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_complexity)? Steve and Phuong's book is relatively easy to read.

Comment: I enjoyed the presentation given by Olaf Beyersdorff in Helsinki this summer. Check out [his slides here](http://satsmt2013.ics.aalto.fi/slides/Beyersdorff.pdf).

Answer (score 13):

It depends on what kind of a "beginner" level you wish to have. I don't think there is a real good undergraduate level text on proof complexity (this is probably true for most specialized sub-areas in complexity). But for a beginner (graduate level) sources, I would recommend, something like understanding well the basic exponential size lower bound on resolution refutations of the pigeonhole principle (via random restrictions, width-size tradeoff and feasible interpolation), and to expand from that point further. This could be achieved (approximately) as follows:

1. Stasys Jukna, Extremal Combinatorics With Applications in Computer Science, 2001, Springer-Verlag, Section 4.8.
2. Eli Ben-sasson and Avi Wigderson, Short Proofs are Narrow - Resolution made Simple (2000), JACM.
3. P. Beame and T. Pitassi, Propositional proof complexity: Past, present, and future, Current trends in theoretical computer science: Entering the 21st century (G. Paul, G. Rozenberg, and A. Salomaa, editors), World Scientific Publishing, 2001, pp. 42--70.
4. Pavel Pudlák, Lower bounds for resolution and cutting planes proofs and monotone computations, The Journal of Symbolic Logic, vol. 62 (1997), no. 3, pp. 981-998.

You can also consult the more self contained and lengthy text:

- Peter Clote and Evangelos Kranakis, Boolean Functions and Computation Models (Chapter 5)

For the more *logical* side of proof complexity, as Kaveh suggested, you can start reading the first chapters of:

- Stephen Cook and Phuong Nguyen, Logical Foundations of Proof Complexity (Perspectives in Logic, Cambridge Press, 2010).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will dig in to these and see how they turn out

Answer (score 6):

For the more algebraic side of proof complexity I recommend starting with Pitassi's 1996 survey paper:

- T. Pitassi. [Algebraic propositional proof systems](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~toni/Papers/pitassi-algebraic.ps), in DIMACS Series in Discrete Mathematics and Theoretical Computer Science, Volume 31, Descriptive Complexity and Finite Models, Immerman and Kolaitis (Eds.), pp. 215-244, 1996.

For a quick overview you might also consult Chapter 5 of the Clote--Kranakis book already mentioned by Iddo, which has a section on algebraic proof systems.

The first research paper I'd recommend reading (both because it's seminal and because it's a pleasant read) is the paper in which the Groebner or Polynomial Calculus proof system was introduced:

- Clegg, Matthew; Edmonds, Jeffery; Impagliazzo, Russell. [Using the Groebner basis algorithm to find proofs of unsatisfiability](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/237814.237860) STOC 1996, 174-183. (Also available from author's webpages without paywall.)

Answer (score 6):

I find these introductory lecture notes easy to read: [Paul Beame's IAS Lectures](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~sabhar/publications/iaspcmi-proofcomplexity00.pdf)

Comment: The notes from Paul Beame's IAS lectures are very nice and give a good overview of the area. One thing to be aware of, though, is that there are some problems with some statements of the "if pigs can fly" type theorems. I tried to give corrected versions in (the mini-survey in) Chapter 4 of my PhD thesis:

_Jakob Nordström. Short Proofs May Be Spacious: Understanding Space in Resolution. PhD thesis, Royal Institute of Technology, Stockholm, Sweden, May 2008_ ([www.csc.kth.se/~jakobn/research/PhDthesis.pdf](http://www.csc.kth.se/~jakobn/research/PhDthesis.pdf)).

Answer (score 5):

The most recent and up-to-date general-purpose proof complexity survey is probably that of Nathan Segerlind:

*Nathan Segerlind: The Complexity of Propositional Proofs. Bulletin of Symbolic Logic 13(4): 417-481, 2007 (http://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/bsl/1304/1304-001.ps).*

And now, warnings for two shameless self plugs…

An even more recent survey, but more narrowly focused on questions regarding proof size, proof space, and size-space trade-offs, is:

*Jakob Nordström. Pebble Games, Proof Complexity, and Time-Space Trade-offs. Logical Methods in Computer Science, volume 9, issue 3, article 15, September 2013 (http://www.lmcs-online.org/ojs/viewarticle.php?id=674).*

There are also some lecture notes from a somewhat recent course I gave on the "low-end spectrum" of proof complexity (i.e., comparatively weak proof systems such as resolution, polynomial calculus, and cutting planes) and connections to SAT solving. These notes can be found at http://www.csc.kth.se/~jakobn/teaching/proofcplx11/#scribe-notes (some are still in progress but the ones that are available should be in good shape).